# Missing X-CSRF-TOKEN in Vue headers

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vue.js, csrf

I'm trying to make a POST using VueJS 1.0.28 but I'm getting a Laravel 5.3 `TokenMismatchException` error.

This is in `app.js` to cover both jQuery and Vue:

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This is in the `main.blade.php` layout where we instantiate the `Laravel` value:

```
<script src="{!! asset('/js/app.js') !!}"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        window.Laravel = {
            csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        };
    })();
</script>
```

When I look at the headers in the POST request, I don't see the X-CSRF included for Vue.

This is super basic stuff for jQuery and I'm a stumped what I misconfigured on the Vue side. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, both Vue and jQuery were getting the token, but the package code I was using was directly using `XMLHttpRequest` so it needed to get the token manually by doing:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Move to Vue 2.* if possible.
2. Don't mix Vue and jQuery. I promise, it will make your life easier.
3. For handling AJAX use e.g. AXIOS
4. If so, you will have just to use: `axiosDefaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrfToken;`

Comment: #1 not an option right now. #2 requirement of the project due to dependencies. #3 I'll look into it, but have no control over which lib the various packages use.